# Rails: How to make nested form only do validation for the outside model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

====== CODE =====
Model father.rb & son.rb

```
class Father < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sons
  validates :f_name, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sons
end

class Son < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :father
  validates :s_name, presence: true
end
```

_form.html.erb--fathers

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :f_name %>
  <%= f.fieids_for :sons do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.s_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

fathers_controller.rb

```
def create
  @father = Father.new father_params
  if @father.save
    do_something
  end
end
```

======= QUESTION ======
If I save father object like below, it will do validations for both father and son.
Instead, if I change it to `@father.save(validate: false)`, I think this will jump both validations.
What I want is only to do validation for father's attribute. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the code below to your model **father.rb** so that basicly you are rejecting son's attribute from validation and only the father's attribute will be validated:

```
reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['s_name'].blank? }
```

The final model **father.rb** will be:

```
class Father < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sons
  validates :f_name, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sons,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['s_name'].blank? }
end
```

**UPDATE**

---

( **NOTE:** The code above won't save `:s_name` attribute into DB, as @Marco Song didn't mention in his question)

The solution which works for me, is to add `allow_blank: true` to Son model. `allow_nil: true` didn't work for me in **Rails 5.0.0.1, Ruby 2.3.1**

Also I added `inverse_of`: to both models to avoid SQL queries, not generating them.

Father model:

```
app/models/father.rb
class Father < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sons, inverse_of: :father
  validates :f_name, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sons
end
```

Son model:

```
app/models/son.rb
class Son < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :father, inverse_of: :sons
  validates :s_name, presence: true, allow_blank: true
end
```

I whitelisted son's attributes in Father's controller:

```
def father_params
  params.require(:father).permit(:f_name, sons_attributes: [:id, :s_name])
end
```

At the end after this setup above, I was able to save `:s_name` attribute in the DB.

Comment: I tried your solution. No error happens. But it seems that it will result in only father model's attributes can be saved, when I checked the log I found that the there is no sql insert statement for son's attribute and the nested son's attribute won't be saved.

Comment: When you try to save attribute to DB, what are you getting from the console? If you are getting something like: "Unpermitted parameters" you should whitelist son's attribute in father's controller: `params.require(:father).permit(:f_name, sons_attributes: [:id, :s_name])`

Comment: I'm glad that you figure out. `allow_nil: true` didn't work for me in Rails 5. I updated my answer in case someone comes to this post with similar problem.

Comment: If you don't find my answer useful, you can answer on your own question and explain to other users, so that whole SO community can benefit out of it :-) Cheers!

Comment: Hi, rails guides says allow_nil and allow_blank are different. allow_nil only allow nil, allow_blank allow both nil and blank string like this "" , so I think it does not work the same for you maybe because the situation is different.

Comment: You mean my setup is different? Yes, I'm aware of differences between both, that's why I'm encourage you to answer to your own question it can help the others, and you can edit your question too, specifying that you want to save :s_name attribute into DB.